# Hydroxy Protecting Groups that are not Cleaved Under Acidic Conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, protecting-groups

I am currently designing a synthesis requiring the use of hydroxy protecting groups. The problem I am having is that the protecting group must be able to survive highly acidic conditions. I would have loved to use a TMBS protecting group since it can withstand LAH, lewis acids, and strong base; however, not acidic conditions. I really do not want to have to use a t-butyl ether protecting group, as its removal requires very harsh conditions. I will provide a scheme indicating all of the conditions I have proposed so far (this scheme is just a rough draft, so there are a few reagents that I have changed to be compatible with the reaction, but the general conditions should remain the same). Does anyone know any protecting groups that would match this criteria? I am only referring to replacing the TMBS protecting group on the second intermediate.

[image]

Comment: A substituted benzyl ether such as 4-nitrobenzyl, or 2,2,2-trichloroethyl ether. I wouldn't do the sulfonation step to block that site

Comment: Do you know of any other good blocking groups? If I could use a blocking group that didn't involve such harsh conditions, I might be able to use a silyl ether protecting group (if I altered some of the other steps of course)

Comment: Why use a blocking group? If you form methoxymethyl ethers of the hydroxyls of the diphenol then you can put in both your carbon chains by sequential directed lithiations and cut your number of steps drastically.

Comment: How about Br? Then you can put your second carbon chain in by a Pd catalysed coupling

Comment: If I first converted the hydroxy groups from the second step into -MOM groups, would that not direct the metalation to occur where the -SO3H is now since both of the -MOM groups are strong ortho-directors?

Comment: It would, just put your carbon chains in different order. Or put in Br

Comment: Monoprotection of phloroglucinol will be difficult. You plan to protect it under basic conditions with a tertiary bromide? What about elimination? It is helpful to number structures to facilitate discussion.

Comment: I've included an updated scheme with numbered intermediates. The first step is an esterification via an Sn1 mechanism. I will achieve this by heating a dilute solution of my tertiary iodide (dilute to prevent poly esterification) in phloroglucinol as my solvent and nucleophile.

Comment: I'm concerned about the selectivity of the bromination 2 to 3. There may be enough steric hindrance that 3 is the major product, won't know until you try

Comment: On step 6, the diels-alder reaction, there are two possible ways in which the dienophile can attack the diene; however, in my mechanism, the less sterically hindered route is shown as the product. Will this be the case, or will there be a large percentage of the minor product?